# What's going on in this program, and, more importantly, why?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Please help me understand this program's execution and what concepts apply here in the larger sense? An illustration which explains thread(s)/stack(s) creations and destruction would be helpful.

```
class Joining {

    static Thread createThread(final int i, final Thread t1) {
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(i+1);
                try {
                    t1.join(); 
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                System.out.println(i+2);
            }
        };
        System.out.println(i+3);
        t2.start(); //1
        System.out.println(i+4);
        return t2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createThread(10, createThread(20, Thread.currentThread()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to know? What happens if you execute the code? What do you not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The inner createThread call is called at the bottom from the main thread [M], with the arguments 20 and the current thread.
2. This call prints 23.
3. A new thread [A] is started (and will be returned) which prints 21, and waits for the main thread [M] to die (and will print 22 after it does).
4. This call prints 24.  It's impossible to know if this will happen before the new thread [A] prints 21.
5. This call returns the new thread [A], which is waiting for the main thread [M] to die.
6. The new thread [A] is passed as the second argument to the createThread call with 10 as the first argument.
7. This call prints 13.
8. Another new thread [B] is started (and will be returned although nobody is catching this return) which prints 11, and waits for the first created thread [A] to die (and will print 12 after it does).
9. This call prints 14.  It's impossible to know if this will happen before this second new thread [B] prints 11.
10. This call returns the second new thread [B], which is waiting for the first created thread [A] to die, but nothing is being done with this return call.
11. The main thread [M] runs out of things to do and dies.
12. When the main thread [M] dies, the join() call on the first created thread [A] returns.
13. The first created thread [A] prints 22.
14. The first created thread [A] dies.
15. When the first created thread [A] dies, the join() call on the second created thread [B] returns.
16. The second created thread [B] prints 12.
17. The second created thread [B] dies.
18. The JVM shuts down, because all threads have died.

Comment: after starting a thread at (3.) i.e t2.start() why will it always execute the next line to print 24 at (4.). Because once you start a thread isn't it possible that instead of printing 24 the run() of t2 will start executing and print 21 before 24. I am asking why is 24 consistently the output here because we dont know how jvm is working here.

Comment: When `t2.start()` executes, the thread is started and the call returns immediately.  The thread calling `t2.start()` immediately goes on to execute the next line.  The only unknown thing is how long will the JVM take to start up this thread?  That's why I don't know whether 21 or 24 will print first.  They will both print at about the same time, though.

Comment: The new thread, before it calls `join()`, will be executing in parallel to the old thread which started it.  Both threads will be going and will be sharing CPU cycles.  In a multi-threaded CPU or a multi-core CPU or a multi-CPU machine, these threads can actually be executed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some debug-output will probably help you understand the execution:

```
import static java.lang.Thread.currentThread;

class Joining {

    static int count = 0;

    static Thread createThread(final int i, final Thread t1) {
        System.out.println("Create thread with " + i + " and " + t1.getName());
        Thread t2 = new Thread("Thread " + count++) {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + ": " + (i+1));
                try {
                    System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + ": join with " + t1.getName());
                    t1.join(); 
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + ": " + (i+2));
            }
        };
        System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + ": " + (i+3));
        System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + ": starting thread " + t2.getName());
        t2.start(); //1
        System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + ": " + (i+4));
        return t2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread someThread = createThread(20, currentThread());
        System.out.println("After first createThread.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        createThread(10, someThread);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Create thread with 20 and main
main: 23
main: starting thread Thread 0
main: 24
After first createThread.
Thread 0: 21
Thread 0: join with main
Create thread with 10 and Thread 0
main: 13
main: starting thread Thread 1
main: 14
Thread 1: 11
Thread 1: join with Thread 0
Thread 0: 22
Thread 1: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...seems to me like the `t1.join` will hang forever on the first createThread(20, Thread.currentThread)) call.

Comment: ...until the main thread terminates. Then the "20" thread will terminate, allowing for the "10" thread to join the "20" thread and then terminates.  In shorts: t20 waits for main to terminate, t10 waits for t20 to terminates, main terminates, so t20 terminates so t10 terminates.